# Skullcandys or Skullcandies?

Tags: grammatical-number, proper-nouns

'Skullcandy' is a plural noun but can also refer to a product, so will the plural be Skullcandys or Skullcandies?

Comment: If _Skullcandy_ patterns on candy, it is either a singular count noun (I'd like a candy) or a mass noun (Too much candy is bad for the teeth). However, the manufacturers can mangle the terminology as they wish – if they use a plural form 'Skullcandyz', that's what it is. But this is hardly mainstream English.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks about the plural form of a word not in the English lexicon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skullcandy isn't a prouduct, it's a brand. So it would be better if you said "Skullcandy Headphones" or "Skullcandy speakers".

The brand is not synonymous with a product, although better known brands do seem to be referred to as my "Nikes", for example. But nearly everyone around the world is familiar with Nike, and not necessarily as many people know about Skullcandy, so you'd be better off referring to a specific item.

Comment: I'm unsure as to how the brand actually has the name trademarked, sorry about that.